# What are the rules around dropping at different stages of building stacks of normal iteration trees?

Tags: set-theory

So my question is about the definitions of the games $\mathcal{G}_k(\mathcal{M}, \alpha, \theta)$ and $\mathcal{W}_k(\mathcal{M}, \omega)$ as defined respectively on the pages 1625 and 1653 from the "An Outline of Inner Model Theory" article in the handbook.

So in each definition, we are dealing with a stack of trees $\langle \mathcal{T}_\xi: \xi < \alpha\rangle$ and each has some last model $\mathcal{Q}_\xi$ and player $I$ chooses some initial segment $\mathcal{P}_\xi$ of $\mathcal{Q}_\xi$ and we build $\mathcal{T}_{\xi+1}$ on that. But the definition of an iteration strategy for such games requires player $II$ to win, by choosing wellfounded branches through these stacks, so for sufficiently large $\xi$, we must have $\mathcal{P}_\xi = \mathcal{Q}_\xi$.

Now, this confuses me, as player $I$ can easily ruin the game for player $II$, by always choosing $\mathcal{P}_\xi$ to be a proper initial segment of $\mathcal{Q}_\xi$, insuring that player $II$ never wins. I think I may be missing something obvious here, but as it stands, the definition seems odd. Is it possible that player $II$ chooses $\mathcal{P}_\xi$? Or maybe does player $I$ need to obey additional rules, which forces them to drop to proper initial segments only boundedly many times? In any case, I would appreciate any sort of clarification. Also, the more important case for me is the definition of $\mathcal{W}_k(\mathcal{M}, \omega)$, in case you would want to take a look at its definition.

Happy Easter everyone!

Comment: Have you looked at the more detailed description in FSIT?

Comment: Actually, no. That's a good idea. I'll take a look now.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, so I just looked in FSIT, and the closest thing I found is definition 5.1.4(2), which in essence is very different in the sense that there we don't allow player $I$ to drop at the end of each iteration tree on their own free will. I unfortunately couldn't find an equivalent of $\mathcal{W}_k(\mathcal{M}, \omega)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Player I does choose the segment $P_\xi$, as it's stated in the handbook article. And player I (maybe) can  indeed win by always choosing $P_\xi$ as a proper segment of $Q_\xi$. But that's no problem. If player I can always arrange this, then that would certainly be a winning strategy for them, so in that case the premouse isn't iterable (or weakly iterable, respectively), and in a strong way. Note that in a rather trivial case, the premouse is just some $L_\alpha$, or $L$ itself, and only finitely many such drops can occur.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks Farmer!